# Running command with subprocess raises FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to run the following commands in a Python script

```
import subprocess
image_name = "alpine:3.10"
scan_image = "trivy -q image -f json {}".format(image_name)
scan_result = subprocess.check_output(scan_image.split()).decode('utf-8')
```

If I run it from a Python script, it raises the following error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trivy'

But if I run the command using python interpreter (interactive mode) it works fine.

```
-bash-4.2# python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> image_name = "alpine:3.10"
>>> scan_image = "trivy -q image -f json {}".format(image_name)
>>> subprocess.check_output(scan_image.split()).decode('utf-8')
'[\n  {\n    "Target": "alpine:3.10 (alpine 3.10.5)",\n    "Type": "alpine",\n    "Vulnerabilities": null\n  }\n]'
>>>
```

What could I be doing wrong? I've run the commands using Python2 and Python3 interpreters.

Comment: What happens if you replace `trivy` in the script with the results of `which trivy` from a shell?

Comment: Using `.format()` and then `.split()` is a _really_ bad idea; it'll fail badly with names containing spaces. Just pass your argument list _as a list_.

Comment: (Yes, the immediate issue is almost certainly that `trivy` isn't in the PATH; but this code is not safe to use with arbitrary filenames).

Comment: ...consider what happens if someone creates a file named something like `'/uploads/ -o /etc/passwd .jpg'` and you run your script over the contents of `/uploads` -- because the `.split()` splits on the spaces that are there inside the name, you get `-o` and `/etc/passwd` passed as separate arguments to `trivy`, overwriting the named file if run by a user with the relevant permissions; replace with any other filename an attacker might want to modify.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, I only did it because I know exactly the command I'm running, but I will  change it.

Comment: @JacobIRR it works if i replace trivy with /usr/local/bin/trivy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security concerns aside, you need to provide the full path to your executable:

Replace `trivy` in the script with the results of `which trivy` from a shell

Comment: Great advice for e.g. Linux, but what about systems like Windows which don't have `which`?

Comment: Windows has `where`. I know this user is in Unix land though because of this line in the OP `-bash-4.2# python3`

Comment: `which` isn't appropriate in bash -- `command -v trivy` is the POSIX-compliant shell-builtin approach (for use with `shell=True`), `type trivy` is the bash one (for `['/bin/bash', '-c', 'type trivy']`). `which` is an external command that isn't POSIX-specified, which the OS may or may not provide. (That's different for zsh, which provides a `which` builtin, but that's yet another shell).

Comment: yeah `type` is my fallback for `which`